# Transffering 2D array to Database

Tags: android, multidimensional-array, android-sqlite

I am developing a simple application for storing student name and roll number into a database. There are two fields for each student. i have managed to get all the students data into a two dimensional array. i heard from someone that you can transfer an array directly to database for storing. if it is possible how should i transfer the 2 dimensional array to database table. The table also have two columns , roll_no and s_name. how can the 2 dimensional arrays data be stored in that table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why someone would tell you that you can "transfer" an array directly to the database. You can store text and only text in sqlite. [There's a provision for describing the data](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) via "affinity", but, underneath, it's just text.

There's a simple solution to your problem, though. Convert the 2d array to a string representation by joining all the entries. Converting it back by splitting the retrieved string. There's lots of sample code out there for splitting and joining.

Comment: you could store it as an image - sqlite understand blobs. But the big question is why would you do something so bizarre?

Comment: @Martin 
I dont want to store the array in database, i just want to store the text in the 2d array to a table in the database. the 2d array contains roll nos and names . how do i do it